# При наведении на DIV возле него появление другого DIV

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть блоки фиксированной ширины и высоты, например по 100px. Они все стоят по порядку один за одним по {float: left;}. Таких блоков может быть любое количество. Теперь когда я навожу на один из этих блоков, рядом, грубо говоря немного ниже курсора, должен появляться информационный блок. Там будет описываться информация о том блоке, на который я навел. Вот

```js
$("body").on("mouseover", "[data-info]", function() {
  $("#" + $(this).data("info") + "").addClass("active");
});

$("body").on("mouseout", "[data-info]", function() {
  $("#" + $(this).data("info") + "").removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.div {
  float: left;
  color: #333;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.div:hover {
  color: blue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.info {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #eee;
  opacity: 0;
}

.info.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-info="log1" class="div">№1</div>
<div data-info="log2" class="div">№2</div>

<div id="log1" class="info">Блок 1</div>
<div id="log2" class="info">Блок 2</div>
```

я сделал что-то подобное, но проблема в том, что инфо-блоки появляются где-то в конце.

А должен появляться как-то так:

[image: А должен появляться как-то так]

Я понимаю, что мне нужно просто правильно настроить стили для info-блоков, но я не знаю как. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно применить `position: absolute;` к классу `.info`.

Так же требуется отслеживать передвижение мыши и применять их к тултипу:

```
const offset = 14;
var mouseX;
var mouseY;
$(document).mousemove( function(e) {
   mouseX = e.pageX; 
   mouseY = e.pageY;
});

$("body").on("mousemove", "[data-info]", function() {
  $("#" + $(this).data("info")).css({'top':mouseY+offset,'left':mouseX+offset}).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Так же `offset` - это значение смещения относительно курсора.

Что получилось в итоге:

```js
const offset = 14;
var mouseX;
var mouseY;
$(document).mousemove( function(e) {
   mouseX = e.pageX; 
   mouseY = e.pageY;
});  

$("body").on("mouseover", "[data-info]", function() {
  $("#" + $(this).data("info")).addClass("active");
});

$("body").on("mousemove", "[data-info]", function() {
  $("#" + $(this).data("info")).css({'top':mouseY+offset,'left':mouseX+offset}).fadeIn('slow');
});

$("body").on("mouseout", "[data-info]", function() {
  $("#" + $(this).data("info")).removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.div {
  float: left;
  color: #333;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.div:hover {
  color: blue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.info {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #eee;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.info.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-info="log1" class="div">№1</div>
<div data-info="log2" class="div">№2</div>

<div id="log1" class="info">Блок 1</div>
<div id="log2" class="info">Блок 2</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое!!!